# El condicional IF no me funciona cuando no hay registros

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

¿El condicional IF en MySQL no funciona cuando no hay registros? estoy tratando de mostrar una columna que indique el estatus de aprobado o no aprobado de un registro (en caso de existir) pero en caso de que no exista pues... que me lo indique también.
Estoy tratando de jugar con consultas sin registros y en caso de eso pues arrojar un resultado...

```
SELECT if(sub.statusid=3, "Aprobado pero sin registros", "No aprobado y sin registros") as 'Afiliado', cc.name as 'currency', SUM(DISTINCT cp.amount) as 'amount', cpr.reference, cpr.datetime, sub.serviceid as 'serviceId' FROM card_payment AS cp INNER JOIN card_payment_response AS cpr ON cpr.idcardpayment = cp.idcardpayment INNER JOIN currency AS cc ON cp.currencyid=cc.currencyid INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.userid = cp.userid INNER JOIN subscription AS sub ON sub.companyid = u.companyid WHERE true AND sub.statusid=3 AND STR_TO_DATE(cpr.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(cpr.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') AND (cpr.reference IS NOT NULL AND cpr.reference != '') AND sub.companyid=1 AND sub.serviceid=1;
```

Comment: Es que estas utilizando INNER JOIN donde la relación debe existir. Utiliza LEFT o RIGTH JOIN sobre la tabla mandataria y en tu if añade la condición de nulo para saber si se dio o no la relaco9n

Comment: Tu consulta previamente incluye la condición sub.statusid = 3. ¿Por qué evaluar esa condición en un IF si todos los datos que llegues a tener ya la cumplen?